# Can I upload my app on itunes connect for testing?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I don't want to release my app just yet, what I want is..I want to test its: 
rate my app function..
like function..
database execution 
and etc

if coming from an appstore download..is that possible?
and how do I do that?

Comment: There is a very simple answer to this **NO** this is impossible through itunesconnect and if you had bother spending some time ready the Apple Documentation on itunesconnect (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/CreatingiTunesConnectRecord.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1) you will have known this a little bit of research goes a long way and means another question isn't asked Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that using the App Store.

What you can do is use a third-party service such as [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/) or [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) to distribute your app to your beta testers. Note that Apple recently acquired TestFlight's parent company, so I'm not sure if TestFlight are accepting new users at the moment.

Comment: @JohnTopley : TestFlight does accept new users, but you can't add their SDK to a non already registered app anymore. This means you can't track usage and crashes, notify testers, and else, but you can still use their tool to deploy your app.